# Display all orders in which a certain product was purchased - Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I've searched all over many sites today and I am unable to find an answer to this.  I am trying to display all orders in which a certain product (scarf) was purchased. For Example:

```
Order #1
Hat            $3.00
Scarf          $5.00

Order #2 
Puzzel         $2.00

Order #3 
Scarf          $5.00
```

With this example, I'd like to display records #1 and #3, in which a scarf was purchased, but also include "Hat" that was purchased along with the scarf in Order #1...(while excluding Order #2)

Output should be:

```
Order #1
Hat            $3.00
Scarf          $5.00

Order #3 
Scarf          $5.00
```

I've tried using instr functions to filter this information out, as well as looks for various formulas, but I cannot seem to figure this out.  I appreciate everyone's time!

John

Answer (score 0):

Create a SOL-expression field:

```
// {%order_has_scarf}
// assumes table in main report is `orders`
(
SELECT  count(1) total
FROM    orders o
WHERE   o.order_id = orders.order_id
)
```

Alter record-selection formula:

```
AND {%order_has_scarf} > 0
```

Comment: Thanks Craig, I'm not sure where I would create this SQL expression field.  Would it be as a Formula Field?  Assuming it would be, when I try to create this, I get the following error "The ) is missing"...The word "total" is highlighted after the error is displayed.  Here is the formula I wrote with actual field names:  (
SELECT  count(1) total
FROM    V_ORDERHEADITEMS o
WHERE   o.{V_ORDERHEADITEMS.ORDERNO} = {V_ORDERHEADITEMS.ORDERNO}
)

Answer (score 0):

Create a group of orders first then place the fields in detail (Hat..etc) and write a supress condition for detail and group like:

```
if Order="PUZZEL"
then true
else false
```

with this condition if puzzel is encountered then both detail and group are supressed.

Comment: Thank you Siva, but I actually have hundreds of product descriptions that I would need to filter, and this may prove to be a little tough to filter one by one

Comment: but in question you have mentioned only `Puzzle` if your question is something different let us know will try to help

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to give a very simple example.  Basically, I want to show all orders that include "Scarf", including all products that were purchased along with a "Scarf" in a single order.  I want to exclude orders in which a "Scarf" was not purchased at all.  This application sells hundreds of products, and the staff are trying to find out how many scarfs were purchased, as well as the products purchased along with a scarf

Comment: To the extent I know if you are trying to explicitly filter something then you need to hardcode the values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i actaully figured out how to do this.  I added another instance of the Order Details table to my crystal report, then I filtered that table by the Item ID related to the scarf, then linked that to the original order table...that way, only orders containing this particular Item ID would be passed to the original table.

Hope this makes sense!